# how to publish a nest package with npm?

Tags: npm, package, nestjs

I have developed a user login module in nestjs, and I need to publish that package so that my coworker can integrate it into the main code, how is it done with nestjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as you've built the module by using only code the package needs (i.e. not having extraneous dependencies) this should be done just as any `npm package` is published. After all, NestJS is just a wrapper around Express which is a wrapper around Node's HTTP module. If you need [here is an article on it](https://dev.to/nestjs/publishing-nestjs-packages-with-npm-21fm)